# Fusion table, 'upload quota exceeded' for small KML file

Tags: kml, google-fusion-tables

I am getting  'upload quota exceeded"  in fusion table.

This is puzzling because I did not exceed 10% of my google drive storage and my KML file contains only 741 rows.  What would cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Fusion Tables have separate quotas:

```
100 MB per table
250 MB total among all your tables
```

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using#quota